# Timer com tempo de sessão ativa: Momento de expiração no cookie - momento autal

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, token, timer

Estou trabalhando com Angular e, quando guardo o token de acesso em um cookie, também guardo (em um outro cookie) seu tempo de expiração (30 minutos). Quero fazer um timer que mostra ao usuário quanto tempo ele ainda tem de sessão, porém estou tendo algumas dificuldades.

Quero que o timer funcione da seguinte maneira:
Sempre que alguém entra no componente inicial do Angular, é pego no cookie o momento em que irá expirar o token e feito um cálculo baseado no momento atual e são salvos os minutos e segundos restantes em duas variáveis do tipo number. Que irá se atualizar e diminuir automaticamente com a função setInterval().

Alguém tem alguma ideia como eu faço essa matemática? Não posso simplesmente pegar a diferença de minutos e segundos, pois digamos que no cookie esteja que a sessão expirará às 17:20, e agora são 16:51, eu terei uma diferença de 31 (usando a função Math.abs()) minutos, o que está errado.
Eu precisaria de alguma maneira para converter tudo isso para o mesmo formato, subtrair e depois reconverter para minutos e segundos novamente.

Talez resolveria se eu multiplicasse os minutos por 60 para transformar em segundos e subtrair. Mas tem-se a questão da virada do dia, em que a expiração pode ser 00:10 e o tempo atual 23:50 tornando esse método não funcional. E, assim como temos a virada do dia, temos a do mês e do ano. E nem todos os meses tem a mesma quantidade de dias para eu sair multiplicando assim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui fazer o que queria. Com a função getTime() da classe Date.
Basicamente pego ambos os tempos em milisegundos com a função e, depois de calcular a diferença, transformo a diferença

```
console.log(`Expiração ${expirationDate.getMinutes()}:${expirationDate.getSeconds()}`)
console.log(`Agora ${new Date().getMinutes()}:${new Date().getSeconds()}`)

let difference = expirationDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime()

console.log(`Diferença ${Math.trunc((difference / 1000)  / 60)}:${Math.trunc((difference / 1000) % 60)}`)
```